# "expected string or buffer"

Tags: python, string

I have this code:

```
x=os.system("host www.google.com")
b=re.findall(r'\w',x)
print b
```

But this returns the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: give us a hint about the environment you are using.

Comment: full stack trace. http://sscce.org/ and http://v.gd/whathaveyoutried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value from [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) is the exit code of the process. This is an integer, not a string, so you're basically doing this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I think the function you're looking for is [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.check_output(['host',  'www.google.com'])
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.147
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.99
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.103
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.104
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.105
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.106
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400c:c03::6a
```